# Administrative fees on a no-show?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, fees-and-charges

I just bought a very cheap ticket with [UIA](https://www.flyuia.com). I plan to do my travel, but in case anything happens I know I lose little money.

However, I can read on my receipt that for my super-economy ticket....

> Cancellation: not allowed
>   Change of reservation: pay administrative fees
>   No-show: pay administrative fees

What? If I change my mind and choose to screw that trip up do I have to pay additional fees that I don't know about?
Can someone explain by their experience?

If I choose to cancel the trip, what should I do to lose only the money I paid tonight for purchasing my ticket?

Comment: chances are these "fees" are the value of the ticket. Eg you buy a $100 ticket and if you no-show, they charge you $100, so you have no "balance" left. But read the terms and conditions to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Their official contract of carriage states](https://www.flyuia.com/ua/en/information/rules-and-regulations/carriage-rules):

> 8.1.9. If a passenger does not show up for the flight («No-Show») where he/she has confirmed reservations and fails to inform the air
>   carrier about changes in his/her travel in advance, the air carrier
>   shall be entitled to cancel the reservation for this flight and for
>   the next segments of the route and the return flight.

As you see, there are no fees mentioned here (unlike many other places, like 6.3).

However if you're really worried about it, according to the contract all you need to do to avoid a "no-show" situation is to notify the airline in advance about changes in your travel plans. There is no documented procedure for that, but in my personal opinion calling/emailing the airline and telling them you're not coming on that flight due to change in you plans should constitute such notification. Or tell the service/gate agent when you're at the airport.

I couldn't find any source of why they mentioned this fee for a no-show, but most likely KateGregory's comment is right - this "fee" is used to drain the value of the ticket - **including airport taxes and fees** - to zero in case of no-show, making it impossible for you to claim a refund.

Comment: Good. Just for the record, going to an airport outside my city just to say the check in agent "hey, please note I'm not flying with you" is not an affordable option :-)

Comment: Interesting interpretation from @KateGregory's comment. I always assumed that the total cost the flight, which includes airport fees, is an "atomic" cost just like any train ticket which includes, but doesn't show, a lot of cost entries. *Maybe* the interpretation is that there is a general rule that a no-show passenger, not having utilized any ground service (security checks, use of toilets, boarding, handling) which is funded by airport fees, could have right to be refunded of that. After all, the airline company only earns money from the "seat reservation" part of the ticket

Comment: Anyway the above was just a comment for sake of discussion

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ the "taxes" portion on your ticket goes to government. My understanding is that if you did not fly, the government doesn't receive those taxes and you shall be able to claim them back. Even RyanAir(!!!) offerst that: https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Flight-Changes-And-Refunds/Can-i-get-a-refund-of-the-government-tax - although they do charge a fee large enough to make it not worthy. Unless you're willing to sue them as the "fee" doesn't seem to be justified by anything. Probably UIA has the same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I've not flown Ukrainian airlines, but I have used other other cheap airlines on super economy tickets, and on occasion not made the flight. All it meant was that the ticket was worthless, so I'd lost the entire cost of the ticket. There were no additional fees to pay, but no duty for the airline to find me another flight.

Comment: That is essentially what the OP is asking; it is not a answer

Comment: The questioner was asking for someone to explain by their experience. That is my experience.

Comment: But the question relates to UIA...